# IIS - How to redirect

Tags: asp.net, iis

How can I redirect `www.example.com/foo` to `www.example.com\subdir\bar.aspx` in IIS?

Note: a file called "foo" does not exist. I'd like to just redirect a URL with that pattern to the second URL

Comment: Do you want to *redirect* them there (as in, their URL will show that they're at /subdir/bar.aspx) or do you merely want to serve the file up that's located at /subdir/bar.aspx and have the URL show as /foo?

Comment: @mason: Redirect is fine. Actually, whichever is easiest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is not redirect, but instead use routing to map the URL to the web form. Then you keep a nice clean URL which is easy for users to type, and it looks better for search engines. We can accomplish that with the [MapPageRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Add this to your Global application class (global.asax or global.asax.cs)

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "foo", "~/subdir/bar.aspx");
}
```

Alternatively, you can add this to your web.config to do a redirect.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="foo">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/subdir/bar.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```